# Is it possible to model a json with class?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase

Short question: is it possible to model a json with a class in TS (/angular) ?
Example:

I'm using Firebase and I have a node /books which looks like:

```
books
  -- 157sq561sqs1
      -- author: 'Foo'
      -- title: 'Hello world'
```

(157sq561sqs1 here is the id of the book)
it will looks:

```
157sq561sqs1 : { author: 'Foo', title:'Hello world'}
```

I tried to model that with:

```
export class Book { 
  id: number;
  author: string;
  title: string;
}
```

But it will looks like:

books

```
  -- 0
      -- id: 157sq561sqs1
      -- author: 'Foo'
      -- title: 'Hello world'
```

Is it possible to model something like that in order to have the model shown ?

Comment: Personally, I wouldnt nest the book properties under the id property in a typescript interface or class. The fact that your persistence store models its content in a different way does not mean that you can not flatten the object representation in typescript.

Comment: So you think I should use my second example as model ? (I already used id as parent for my users node because I saw everybody doing that but maybe I should do that only for users ?)

Comment: I think I'll copy the id in the node itself too so it will be something like 157sq561sqs1 : { id: 157sq561sqs1, author: 'Foo', title:'Hello world'}

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible directly with typescript.You have to write code for that.